# Posting array of fields w

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I have dynamic fields on a bootstrap three. The form has three parts which are presented in tabs.

Form tags are automatically being removed in the modal so I have my fields having out. I can post the rest of the values using the jquery attribute selector $("input[name='invoice-date']").val(). However, my predicament lies here:

```
 <div class="tab-pane" id="tab_2">
                <div class="row">
                  <br/>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-lg-2">
                      <label>#</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-7">
                      <label>Description</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-3">
                      <label>Amount</label>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-lg-2">
                      <label>Item 1.</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-7">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="items[1][description]" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-3">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="items[1][amount]" />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-lg-2">
                      <label>Item 2.</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-7">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="items[2][description]" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-3">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="items[2][amount]" />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-lg-2">
                      <label>Item 3.</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-7">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="items[3][description]" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-3">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="items[3][amount]" />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-lg-2">
                      <label>Item 4.</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-7">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="items[4][description]" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-3">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="items[4][amount]" />
                    </div>
                  </div>
            </div>
       </div>
```

How do I post items value considering it's an array? If I was in a position to enclose the fields in a  tags then a simple .serialize() would work.

This is my ajax post so far:

```
$('#gen-invoice').on('click',function()
{
  $.ajax(
  {
    url: 'path("create-invoice")',
    data: { invoiceDate: $("input[name='invoice-date']").val(), job: $("input[name='inv-job-id']").val(), att: $("input[name='att']").val(), summary: $("input[name='inv-remarks']").val(), additional: $("input[name='inv-add']").val(), vattable: $("input[name='inv-vattable']").val(), items: $("input[name='items[]']").serialize(), deductions: $("input[name='deductions[]']").serialize()  },
    success:  function(response)
    {
      if(response.response == 200)
      {
        window.open(response.path,'_blank');
      }
      else
      {

      }
    }
  }
  )
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not iterate on the items in the invoice?
Start by giving items a distinct class name (.invoice-item).
Then itrate on the items and push them into an array that you can then pass to your ajax call as a parameter.

```
var invoice_items = [];
$(".invoice-item").each(function(){
  invoice_items.push({name: $(this).val(),
  description: $(this).parent().prev().children().val()});
});
```

As you can see the traversing can be done in an easier manner, but it's just to get the point across.

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking there's a selector that I'm not privy to that could help with selection without iteration